# Unable to fully install Selenium Web Driver through 'selenium-webdriver-2.52.0' gem install on windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rubygems, installation, rubymine

The Gem install of Selenium WebDriver is failing with the following error. However the Selenium Webdriver gem is being listed in the List of Gems installed. Please help me resolve this issue.

C:\Users\King Julian XXV>gem install selenium-webdriver
Successfully installed selenium-webdriver-2.52.0

RDoc::Parser::Ruby failure around line 26 of
lib/selenium/webdriver/edge/legacy_support.rb

Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -c lib/selenium/webdriver/edge/legacy_support.rb

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

```
    (RDoc::Error) unknown type of %string "i"
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RDoc::Error)
    unknown type of %string "i"

*Even though the gem was installed successfully and the 'require 'selinium-webdriver' in RubyMine is not able to identify it and shows the following error message as shown in the image.*

[RubyMine not Identifying Selenium WebDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgmnM.png)